# PHP-conditional formatting

Tags: php

The following code prints nicely the table

```
<?php
                $lines = file('graphdata/GapsVsOthersForDimsOthersJson.csv');       

                foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
                    if($lineNum == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    print "         <tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";

                    $tokens = str_getcsv($line);
                    /*print "<td style=\"width: 200px;\">" . trim($tokens[0]) . "</td>";*/
        print "<td style=\"width: 300px;\"><a href=\"" . trim($tokens[7]) . "\">" . trim($tokens[0])  ."</a></td>";       

                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</td>";  
                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[2]) . "</td>";
                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[3]) . "</td>";
                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[4]) . "</td>";
                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[5]) . "</td>";
                    print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[6]) . "</td>";

                    print "</script>\n";

                }
            ?>
```

I want to format the token(4) cell based on values of token(2) and token(3):

Red background if the value is smaller than token(2)-1.1*token(3).
Green background if the value is greater than token(2)+1.1*token(3)

Please advise

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Make a function that returns the appropriate `style=`, code in your conditions, and call it with each output line, embed. (If you attempted anything, share that. Otherwise this is a poor question format.)

Comment: edited below answer (sorry misread original question)

Comment: @JayBlanchard just as an FYI, I thought it was fairly clear what the OP was asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set up some conditional statements.  First of all, I recommend using a stylesheet instead of inline styling; it's much cleaner, so you could simply name some classes for different conditions.

for example, you could do something like this

```
if ($tokens[4] < ($tokens[2]-(1.1*$tokens[3])) {

    echo '<td class="tokenred">' . trim($tokens[4]) . '</td>';
 }   
else if ($tokens[4] > ($tokens[2]+(1.1*$tokens[3])){
    echo '<td class="tokengreen">' . trim($tokens[4]) . '</td>';

}
else {
    echo '<td>' . trim($tokens[4]) . '</td>';
}
```

and then your stylesheet would have something like

```
.tokenred {

    background-color: #FF0000;
}

.tokengreen {

    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

alternately you could use inline styles if you choose

Comment: Thanks, in the first line I get "Fatal error: Function name must be a string"